Difference between conditional probability and naive bayes classifier
I have this dataset



a
b
c
K




1
0
1
1


1
1
1
1


0
1
1
0


1
1
0
0


1
0
1
0


0
0
0
1


0
0
0
1


0
0
1
0



I'm trying to calculate the probability of
P(K=1 ∣ a=1 ∧ b=1 ∧ c=0) using a Naive Bayes Classifier
If I expand the expression using Bayes' Theorem I get the correct result (which is 1/2).
What I don't understand is when I try the intuitive method, i.e.:
Let's say a=1 ∧ b=1 ∧ c=0 is the event D
Then the question asks us P(K=1 ∣ D), which should mean P(K=1 ∩ D) / P(D), right?
Well, when I count the rows where a=1, b=1 and c=0 I only count one row (the 4th row).
And when I look at rows where both K=1 and D applies, I count 0 such rows. (the 4th row has K as 0).
Therefore the answer I get this way is 0/1 which is 0. But the correct answer is 1/2 I think.
Can someone explain to me why the latter logic doesn't work? I researched a lot but still can't see why it doesn't work.
Thanks a lot!

You confront us with two different estimators based on two different sets of assumptions.  It should be no surprise they might have different values.

@whuber what are the names of these estimators and what are the two sets of assumptions that differ? I'm trying to understand but it's too confusing to me. Thanks for the comment!

They have a huge number of names.  The "Naive Bayes" classifier coincides with a Bayes estimate with uniform prior.  The second one is the standard Maximum Likelihood estimator as well as the Method of Moments estimator (and many other things, too).
